# WCF service - migrating from https to http

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, service, web

I have a web service in production that is running over https using a certificate. I would like to deploy this to a staging server without a certificate.

So I believe my best approach is to migrate this to a http service on the staging server. I have modified the web.config and changed the security mode to none and can see the running in IE.

When I use a WebClient to access the service I get a 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.' error message.

Can anyone give me some advice on this please?

Thanks

Al

Comment: Did you update the client reference?

Comment: Make sure that the changes made to your server web.config are also made to your client's .config, where applicable

Comment: By WebClient you mean System.Net.WebClient or your custom application-specific service client? Could you post client code if it is System.Net.WebClient?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a permission issue. Check all the permissions. If you had any more problems, you will get extensive error saying multiple things.

Comment: Not a helpful answer - what are "all the permissions" you are asking the OP to check?

Comment: The folder of the WCF service, firewall, read write permission of the WCF service.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you can connect using the WCF Test Client (you can find it inside Visual Studio's `Common7` folder, or just search for `wcftestclient.exe`). If it can connect to the service, you can make it show you the .config files it uses (and you'll be able to cross-check them against yours).